# how to add a value in the span created by the plugin Tag-it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the plugin Tag-it to create some tags. The plugin creates the tags through span, so I would like to know how do I add a value to a tag created by the plugin?

can someone help me?

Comment: How are you using/calling the plugin? Where are the values coming from? What's the (relevant/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML you're starting with?

Comment: I call the plugin like this:

`code`$('#display').tagit('createTag', valor);`code`

where the parameter "value" and past coming from the database

Comment: Whatever code you tried to show in your comment, please edit it into your question (use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16923965/edit) link below the tags).

Comment: I can not put this code between the tags

Answer (score 0):

```
.tagit("fill", [{label: 'valor', value: 12}, {label: 'stuff', value: 13}])
```

From the [documentation](http://webspirited.com/tagit/docs.html)

Comment: 'm not managing to put that code, not add html valur and the teg so appears OBJECT